# Can't add items to array

Tags: swift

I'm having some trouble with an array. I created an array called 'coins'

```
var coins = [Coin]()
```

then appended objects to it within a function

```
 func getCoinData() {
        AF.request("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=10&tsym=USD", encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

            if let json = response.result.value{

                let responseDictionary = json as! [String : Any]
                let data = responseDictionary["Data"] as! [Any]

                for index in data {

                    let coin            = index as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    let coinInfo        = coin["CoinInfo"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    let displayInfo     = coin["DISPLAY"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    let usdDisplayInfo  = displayInfo["USD"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>

                    let name            = coinInfo["Name"]
                    let fullName        = coinInfo["FullName"]
                    let imageUrl        = coinInfo["ImageUrl"]
                    let price           = usdDisplayInfo["PRICE"]
                    let marketCap       = usdDisplayInfo["MKTCAP"]
                    let change24Hr      = usdDisplayInfo["CHANGE24HOUR"]

                    let newCoin = Coin()

                    if let newCoinName = name, let newCoinFullName = fullName, let newCoinImageUrl = imageUrl, let newCoinPrice = price, let newCoinMarketCap = marketCap, let newCoinChange24hr = change24Hr {
                        let coinName        = newCoinName
                        let coinFullName    = newCoinFullName
                        let coinImageUrl    = newCoinImageUrl
                        let coinPrice       = newCoinPrice
                        let coinMarketCap   = newCoinMarketCap
                        let coinChange24Hr  = newCoinChange24hr

                        newCoin.name        = "\(coinName)"
                        newCoin.fullName    = "\(coinFullName)"
                        newCoin.imageURL    = "\(coinImageUrl)"
                        newCoin.price       = "\(coinPrice)"
                        newCoin.marketCap   = "\(coinMarketCap)"
                        newCoin.change24Hr  = "\(coinChange24Hr)"

                        self.coins.append(newCoin)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i print 'self.coins.count' within the scope of the function i can see the count incrementing. Outside the function it's reading 0 items in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Written for `Swift 5`

The problem is that you have a `URL` request which is [Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean). This means that the task is not waited for to complete.

In your problem, inside the function `coins` is printed ***after*** it has been assigned, ***after*** the URL request. However, when `coins` is printed outside the function, it is printed ***before*** it has been changed, as the URL request has **not yet completed**.

To solve this, you need to create a completion handler. A basic one is shown here:

```
// Our errors which could occur
enum SomeError: Error { case unknown }

// Function which is ASYNCHRONOUS
func someAsyncFunction(completion: @escaping (Result<Int, SomeError>) -> ()) {
    // Temporary for this example
    let success = true
    let myNum = 3
    
    // Return value if it is a success, otherwise return the error
    if success {
        completion(.success(myNum))
    } else {
        completion(.failure(.unknown))
    }
}


// Call
someAsyncFunction { (result) in
    print("Result:  \(result)")
    /* PRINT COINS HERE */
}
```

See a full guide on completion handlers using `Result` in `Swift 5` at [`hackingwithswift.com`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift).

Comment: Thanks, you're a live saver.

Comment: @OlijujuanGreen Glad I helped! 